# Como utilizar auto-reload (browserSync) no ionic server quando em um container Docker?

Tags: ionic, ionic3, docker

Realizei a instalação do `ionic 3.20` em um container `Docker`.
Tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém estou com dificuldade para utilizar o recurso de `auto-refresh`, ao alterar um arquivo o conteúdo não é sincronizado com o browser, assim como ocorre quando utilizo o `ionic` fora do container.

Como solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 2):

Verifiquei que estava tudo certo ao utilizar a imagem: https://hub.docker.com/r/fabiojanio/php-apache-nodejs/

Bastava somente liberar a porta do live reload, que são: `35729`